# UniqueValidator throw error when update an email with old email

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have been working on django serializers. Below is my code

```
class UpdateTravelAgentStaffSerializer(ModelSerializer):
      model = User
      fields = (
            'full_name',
            'position',
            'email',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'full_name': {
                'required': True,
            }}
```

When I create new Travel Agent Staff, the validator of   email unique Email Validator works well. Now During update I added same validation during adding of TravelAgentStaff Now Igot error saying email must be unique. The validation I applied in update was as.

```
extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {
                'validators': [
                    UniqueValidator(
                        queryset=User.objects.all()
                    )
                ]
            }
        }
```

So I tried

```
 def validate_email(self, value):
        self.value= value
```

Now I dont know how to check unique email and also the email of current user need to be allowed if it is unchanged.
I have added my views here

```
class UpdateTravelAgentStaffView(generics.UpdateAPIView, TravelAgentMixin):
    """
    Use this end-point to update specific travel agent  staff
    """
    serializer_class = travel_agent_staff_serializers.UpdateTravelAgentStaffSerializer
    # permission_classes = (IsOwnBusCompanyStaff,)

    def get_object(self):
        obj = self.get_travel_agent()
        # self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        return travel_agent_staff_usecases.UpdateTravelAgentStaffUseCase(
            serializer=serializer,
            travel_agent_staff=self.get_object()
        ).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated question,

All you are required to in the `perform_update` to update the details of the agent is simply call serializer.save() method. This will internally call the `update` method of the serializer which will do the needful.

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()         # this will update the details 
        return travel_agent_staff_usecases.UpdateTravelAgentStaffUseCase(
            serializer=serializer,
            travel_agent_staff=self.get_object()
        ).execute()
```

Comment: I am using generic UpdateApiView

Comment: i have added my view code right there for further help

Comment: `UpdateTravelAgentStaffUseCase` is some custom function in your case?

Comment: Yeah I have Custom Function but I think this validation is to be mentioned in serializers

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the edits and updates.

Comment: is there any validation need on serializers?

Comment: I don't think so it will be run internally by the serializer